# How do I reheat a casserole in the oven?

Tags: pasta, reheating, casserole

How long and at what temperature should I reheat a pre-baked casserole or pasta dish for 8 people (9x12) that I am taking to a luncheon?

Comment: See also:  http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/38036/how-long-should-i-reheat-frozen-lasagna

Comment: Since you separately posted [a question about using a microwave](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/42411/how-do-i-reheat-a-casserole-in-the-microwave), I'm going to edit this one to *only* be about using the oven, since that's what we all assumed you meant. (Casseroles are much better heated in the oven.)

Answer (score 4):

There is no single answer.  It depends mostly on thick the casserole is, and how cold it is.

For a not-frozen casserole, I recommend starting with about 3/4 of the original bake time at about 350 F, and then seeing if it is hot enough.  An instant read thermometer in the center should read about 150 F to 160 F for service.

You may need to put foil over the top to prevent over-browning, or increase the heat at the end to about 400 F to encourage more browning, depending on the nature of the particular casserole.

Since you are just heating it through, generally any temperature from about 300 to 400 F is going to work, with an appropriate adjustment to the time, if there are other items in the oven that need a specific temperature.